# Using meta tags gem, how to render metas in content_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-tags

I'm having problems with this Gem, when using content for.

In my application.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<head>
      <% if current_page?(root_path) %>
        <meta name="description" content="My page">
      <% else %>
        <%= yield :description_meta %>
      <% end %>
</head>
```

And then, in my views, I do the following:

```
<% content_for :description_meta do %>
        <% set_meta_tags :description => "My description" %>
<% end %>
```

It wont paint any metas, and if I render it with `<%=`, it will show in the body of the page as normal text.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Read [MetaTags Usage](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags#metatags-usage).

Seems like `set_meta_tags` just configure meta tags and `display_meta_tags` render them.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it!